# Svg Displaying differently / incorrectly only in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have some inline SVG code thats generated at run time.  For some strange reason I get incorrect results in chrome compared to other browsers.

Here it is in chrome..

[image: chrome]

If you look at the further right circle, you will see I have it highlighted in chrome inspection tools, that its what the box box is. Looking at the inspections bounding box, it clearly thinks that the svg is in what I would consider the correct position(end of the line), the svg code itself is also correct(e.g. the coordinates used)...however the actual circle is drawn out of its area.

Here is exactly the same in firefox...

[image: firefox]

Again i have it highlighted in the browsers inspection tools and you can see the circle is exactly where it should be.

Curiously the distance away from its 0,0 (the left most circle) seems to affect how offset the rendered circle is.  Here it is again in chrome and you will see its not offset the same amount

[image: chrome smaller]

I have removed all css (its on in the pictures to make it clearer) and that didn't help.

The fact that its fine in Firefox no matter what, and the chrome inspection tools show its boundary correct leads me to think its a bug / difference in the way it handles svgs in chrome?

If anyone has any suggestions I would very much appreciate your input.

thanks

EDIT: Heres the SVG code:

```
 <svg width="57.59424px" height="57.59424px">
<path d="M28.7969 28.7969 l1351.0526 31.115000000000002" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2px; opacity: 1; stroke-dasharray: 0;"></path>
<circle class="markup-leader-handle markup-leader-start-point" cx="28.796871185302734" cy="28.796875" r="8"></circle>
<circle class="markup-leader-handle markup-leader-control-point" cx="704.3231843241383" cy="44.35441137083379" r="8"></circle>
<circle class="markup-leader-handle markup-leader-target-point" cx="1379.8494974629739" cy="59.911947741667575" r="8"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seeing the actual SVG code and ability to reproduce would go a long way for folks looking to troubleshoot.

Comment: "These are not the elements you're looking for." The code you added just draws a straight line - all the circles are display:hidden. Further - all the shapes are massively overflowing the 57 x 57 SVG box that you're declaring. I'm guessing the CSS is adding a :before or :after pseudo element? And over-riding the display hidden and the SVG sizing - so you need to post the relevant classes too.

Comment: sorry i should have tidied the code before posting - the circles get hidden when deselect - which it must have done when i copied to html code. I do have overflow set to visible...however if I take the width and height off I still get the issue